# DALI Protocol: Is it valid to include this for manchester decoding convenience?

Tags: serial, dali, manchester-coding

**Understanding:** DALI uses Async data decoding using 1 start bit and 2 stop bits. The 1 start bit is logical one (1), also encoded during Manchester encoding and the 2 stop bits(Signal is HIGH for long periods, at least 2*833us) designate the *idle_signal*.

[image]

Now, if I am decoding this data using the measured pulse width method or sampling method, I will not have a ***closing interrupt for last bit "1"***!! I am specifically using pulse-width method decoding for Manchester decoding.

I can solve this problem by checking the LSB bit during Manchester encoding. If LSB is 1, I will include a short reset-set signal at the end. I will make sure that I will ignore the rest of the data after I have received my required frame. Anyway, this short reset-set signal will not fall in my long or short range and I can also stop my timer to respond to any other interrupt after the required frame is received!

**Question:**

1. Is it valid according to DALI standard?? What could go wrong with my approach?
2. In general, which method is used for DALI standard? Sampling-based or pulse-width based??
3. The lack of preamble, does it cause any problems?

Thanks in advance!

PS:

- I am not sure of the terminology "Asynch data decoding", what I meant is that there is no preamble data involved giving the decoder enough time to sync!
- Sampling-based [page 7], pulse-width based [page 6] methods are described in this [app-note](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-9164-manchester-coding-basics_application-note.pdf).
- Image from [this source](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01465A.pdf).

EDIT: My logic of Manchester_Decoding is [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/342578/91099).

EDIT2: [image]

Yeah! It is a clear misunderstanding, as soon as I put the logic on Paper, I got it figured! I was thinking how the last pulse will end if the SIGNAL is high for longer times but as we can see from the figure the last 1 will be decoded before itself.

Still, I wish to know about the general implementation standard for DALI and problems caused by lack of preamble data in DALI context.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you're asking and I'm not sure you understand what a one is with Manchester encoding.Let's start with:  Do you understand that Manchester signals have to change half way through the bit period? Whether it is a one or a zero?

Comment: Yes ! I know that but during data recovery(decoding), I will be comparing the pulse widths, I will not be taking values at 3/4T!! I will edit my question to include my logic as well! and the method I am using is described in the app-note referenced!

Comment: IIRC I ended up doing edge interrupts, measuring how long between edges with a timer and working out whether it was a one or a zero. Then once all 8 or 16 bits had been received, check the line is high for two bit periods. There's more than one way to do it though. I've not looked through your code. TBH I'm still not sure what you're unclear about, I don't understand what you mean by a closing interrupt for last bit one, but if you really don't get one, then your algorithm is not robust enough.

Comment: How do you check that the line is high for a two-bit period with the timer and interrupts?

Comment: I am trying to put my logic as easy as possible and will upload that image soon as EDIT.

Comment: Once you have detected the last bit's last clock edge (either bit 7 or bit 15 depending on send or receive), there is a minimum time that the line has to be high for. I suppose if you're only sampling at regular intervals you just need to ensure the line never goes low for two to two-and-a-half bit periods by sampling at a high enough frequency and checking that the line is always high. Edge triggered interrupts as well as timer are much easier in this respect I think.

Comment: Also, please check your question. You *seem* to be getting encoding and decoding mixed up!

Comment: Yes! I was wrong! Even my logic works! As soon as I put on paper it is clear. Still, two questions remain how is it done in DALI standard? and What are the problems caused by lacking preamble data?

Comment: @DiBosco finally can you please elaborate detecting that the line is high for longer periods(IDLE) on receiving side? If there is no pulse measured, how to deduct its period? I am using timer in input capture mode! Should I need to poll the pin over time to deduct it is IDLE?

Comment: Yes, polling continually and finding no pin change is exactly right. You have to do that anyway to find the start bit. By keeping track of number of samples between changes means you know exactly where you are in the word receive (including stop bit) or that you're between frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for a preamble, this is a very simple protocol. There is a minimum time between frames which means you can very easily detect when the line is idle. Then, once the line goes low during idle time, you measure to make sure the line is high at 3/4T and you know you've had a start bit.

It's asynchronous because there is only a data line, not clock and data. That's nothing to do with DALI per se, that's just a standard communications term.

If you look at the Atmel apps note you referenced, it talks about two different ways of doing the decoding. Ensure your sampling time is quick enough for your chosen sample based method. Personally, I think the mixture of edge interrupts and timer interrupts is less of an overhead as you're not having so many timer interrupts to ensure your sampling time is fast enough. Which leads nicely on to...

..."how the standard does it". It doesn't specify how it is implemented, just that it must be done in a robust way to ensure it works under all circumstances.

Comment: Can you provide any resources for implementation of Decoder using "mixture of edge interrupts and timer interrupts" ?? I am using timer in input capture mode and timer pin is the edge interrupt pin!! Thank you!

Comment: If you look at that Atmel apps note it talks about a timing based method in section 4.1. It's saying that you record the lengths of time between edges by using timers triggered from edge interrupts. That time reveals whether there has been a half clock period or full clock between edges, which means you can track zeros and ones. You need to be aware of where you are in the receiving byte.

Comment: So, for example, the first edge, you know is the mid bit of the start bit. If there is a half bit period for the next edge, you know it should be a zero as it will be going high to low. If there is a full bit period you know it will be going low to high and be a 1 as the first bit of data. It is fairly straightforward to work out when there is an error by keeping track of what possible time periods could come next. Also, at the end of receiving the last bit, you can set a time out for a timer and as long as you don't receive an edge within that period, you know you have your stop bits.

Comment: To answer your last question in your question above. Yes, polling continually and finding no pin change is exactly right. You have to do that anyway to find the start bit. By keeping track of number of samples between changes means you know exactly where you are in the word receive (including stop bit) or that you're between frames.

Comment: Setting timeout is what I am looking for! Anyways this whole confusion because I am using timer_pin in input_capture_interrupt mode, I think it will be more convenient if I use edge interrupt detector and timer separately i.e separate pin for interrupt detector and independent timer! Thanks for your time and patience

Comment: So, the idea of using edge_detector and timer separately is wrong! But I finally have it under control on how to use the timer in input capture mode and make it work the way you are describing!

Comment: It's not wrong, I've used it very successfully! :)

Comment: I agree! It is not wrong :)